# What is the query and randomness complexity for very efficient PCPs?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, pcp

In the 2012 paper *[On the Concrete-Efficiency Threshold of Probabilistically-Checkable Proofs](http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2012/045/)*, the authors state the following (paraphrased from page 11).

> **Theorem 1** (informal). There is a PCP system where, to prove and verify 
>   that a program $P$ accepts the input $(x, w)$ within $T$ steps for some
>   witness $w$ (with $|x|, |w| \leq T )$ [... in parallel time,] the prover runs
>   in parallel time $O((\log T)^2)$, when also given as input the transcript of
>   computation of $P$ on $(x, w)$ [and] the verifier runs in parallel time
>   $O((\log T)^2)$.

I'm having trouble determining whether the authors state the asymptotic randomness used and queries made for this PCP verifier. I see that Lemma C.8 (on page 134) gives an expression for the number of queries used and amount of randomness used. However, I would be grateful if someone could interpret this into a big O notation formula.

> What is the number of queries and amount of randomness used by this PCP
>   verifier?